# Get Executed .jar Name on Windows

Tags: java

I want to get jar name file executed from Windows.
For example, user rename my .jar file become xyz.jar and paced on D:\
So user may executing 
`java -jar D:\xyz.jar`
How do we get the name of that jar file?

```
String pathName = new java.io.File(Application.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getName();
```

is working on Centos 7.5 but not working on Windows 10

Comment: I do not understand what you try to do? What about extracting the content of the JAR archive, and running it EG with `java -cp . MainClass`? Or calling it from another JAR ?

Comment: What does *not working on Windows 10* mean? Any error information?

Comment: @tryingToLearn The OP is using the code suggested in that question, so how is this a duplicate?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and specifically mention what results you do get.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Actually my point of view was that there are multiple solutions suggested in the assumed duplicate but OP has listed 1. But I will remove the flag and add this as a comment instead.